# Hibernate one to one mapping with different tables one can exist without other

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, option-type, one-to-one

I have 2 tables:
1) Transaction table
2) Payment table
Scenario is:
Record in a transaction table can exist without having a record in payment 
table.

I need to have a one-to-one mapping between Transaction and Payment table.
Transaction can be done today and payment can be done sometime later too. But the record in payment table should have a mapping in Transaction table.

Transaction table:
id as primary key

Payment able:
id as primary key
transaction_Id as foreign key referring to id in Transaction table.

I am doing like below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Transaction_Table")
public class Transaction {
  @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SOMESEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SOMESEQ", sequenceName = "SOMESEQ")
@Column(name = "ID",unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "transaction_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Payment payment;

... other properties
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Payment_Table")
public class Payment {
  @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SOMESEQ2")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SOMESEQ2", sequenceName = "SOMESEQ2")
@Column(name = "ID",unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

 @OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Transaction trn;

... other properties
}
```

Now, If I try to insert in Transaction table it give error "constraint violation" for inserting null into transaction_Id of payment table.

How can I change my code so that If I insert into Transaction table then it should not try to insert in payment table. And when I save into Payment table, it get its foreign key value(set when I fetch the record from transaction table- how to set that too? through setter of Payment class?)

Can you guys please suggest?

Comment: Your mapping doesn't match with your description at all. You have two separate OneToOne associations: one is supposed to use a foreign key column in transaction, pointing to payment, but this column is the same as the column used for the transaction ID, which makes no sense. The other is supposed to say that the ID of payment is also the forign key to transaction. In all cases, you don't have any transaction_id foreign key in payment. Read the javadoc of the annotations you're using. read the Hibernate documentation.

Comment: I have edited the column name, that was a mistake. There is only one foreign key i.e in Payment table which refers to Primary key of transaction table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer below link for one-to-one relation in hibernate
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_one_to_one_mapping.htm

Actually there should be same primary key between both tables i.e transaction table's primary key should be also refer to payment table's primary key.